# How to test config file property ? - Kotlin + Spring boot + Junit5

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, properties

I would like to create a new test with a property file, however on running, variables are always setting to null (only on test of course).

There is an issue with kotlin / Spring boot annotation ?

This is my code.

application-test.yml :

```
export:
  path: /tmp/
  filename: reports.csv
```

Test file :

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = [ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer::class])
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = [Config::class])
@ActiveProfiles("test")
internal class ControllerTest {

companion object {
    @MockBean
    var repository1: Repository1 = Mockito.mock(Repository1::class.java)

    @MockBean
    var repository2: Repository2 = Mockito.mock(Repository2::class.java)

    var service: Service = Service(repository1, repository2)
}

// Some mocked object for repo


 @Test
fun `export reports successfully`() {
    val file = service.exportDatabase()

    Assertions.assertEquals(
        null,
        file
    )
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
class IcaoService(
    private val repository1: Repository1,
    private val repository2: Repository2
) {

@Resource
private val config: Config = Config()

    fun exportDatabase(): File {
        val csvFile = File(config.path, config.filename)
        csvFile.createNewFile()

        val headers = listOf("id", "documentId", "mrz", "startDate", "duration", "datagroups", "error")
        val reports = repository2.findAll()
        csvWriter().open(csvFile, append = false) {
            writeRow(headers)
            reports.forEachIndexed { index, report ->
                writeRow(index, report.documentId, report.mrz, report.startDate, report.duration, report.datagroups, report.error)
            }
        }

        return csvFile
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that profile suffixes are used with yaml.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've used a couple of projects with YAML, and I can confirm that profile suffixes _do_ work with it.  Those used simple `@Value` annotations, though; I'm not familiar with the way the `Config` class here is wired, so I can't comment on that.